# Green folder on the UI. Can't drill down into the folder

Tags: github

Github was working.  Then when I commented and I went to github UI and I looked at the repo, for one of the folders I saw a green folder and I can't click on it to drill down.  How do I fix this?

Even further when I check out the repo and I switch to the branch, there is nothing there. Where did the data go?

Comment: With the request for the close..then do make a comment on where else I look look for help. THis is very serious issue and i am sure others have faced this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a **submodule**. Basically, this is a pointer to a specific commit of another repository.

One would usually rely on a submodule in the following (not exhaustive) list of situations

- avoid duplication of code
- state the dependency with another project at a very specific point in time

You can find more information about submodules by reading the following resources

- [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)
- [Git man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)

Below, an example of how GitHub currently display a submodule. On the right of the name, you'll notice the abbreviated form of the commit sha (`7a361e9`) which is being referenced by this submodule.

[image: submodule]

Comment: Thats it!  That was the bane of my existence.  Thanks for clearing that up.