# Git repository from github empty green folder

Tags: git, github

I am pulling a git repository from github.
When I clone the repo there is one empty folder which should have contained a project. Since other projects are referring to this folder.

When I browse the repo on the github the folder shows in green color.

Is there something that I am missing ?

I am using

```
git clone https://github.com/TomTasche/Announcify.droid.git
```

The command works and it clones the repo successfully to my machine, but that green folder is empty , the rest of code is downloaded fine..

check this page of repo
https://github.com/TomTasche/Announcify.droid

Comment: what is `https://path`? It should be something like `git@github.com:username/reponame.git` or for http like `http://github.com/username/reponame.git` (and note that ssh is recommended over http)

Comment: @eis I have updated the path in my question, the path is fine and git starts cloning everything. The only problem is one of the folder is empty and that folder shows green on github

Comment: Why not provide the real URL to the project you are talking about so the community can take a look and hopefully answer your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753027/green-folder-on-the-ui-cant-drill-down-into-the-folder

Comment: @CodeBrickie I thought that would violate terms of stackoverflow, my bad :)

Comment: That folder is a submodule: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a submodule. In your checked out project do `git submodule update --init` and it should fix things.

In the latest versions of git the clone operation has a --recursive option to automatically initialize the submodules but I don't think most tools are using this yet.

`git submodule init dirname` and `git submodule update --init` are the normal commands to create the local copy.

See [the git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html) for more about submodules.

Looking closely at the linked repository - I think you might need to contact the author and get them to commit the .gitmodules file in the toplevel folder as that is where the submodule initialization configuration is stored. Here is a link to another project that has a submodule ([msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit)) for comparison. In that project, the git folder is a submodule.

Comment: when I do git submodule update --init it says no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path API-Announcify

Comment: Like is mentioned - the author has neglected to add the .gitmodules file. If you know where the repository might be located you can just clone it in the right place yourself and that will resolve the issues. A submodule is just a clone with a known commit id to checkout. For doing development you clone and checkout an appropriate branch just like any normal repository.